# How to find the count of elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a span tag and that holds some n number of span tags.. can I get the number of span tags available with in the parent span using Jquery.

example:

```
<span class="x">
    <span id="1">one</span>
    <span id="2">two</span>
    <span id="3">three</span>
</span>
```

now i should find the count of number of span tags inside the parent span and my output is 3 according to the above scenario.

please help me..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

my version :)

```
$('span.x > span').length
```

Comment: I prefer this over the version I posted. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
$("span.x").children("span").size()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AZXv3/

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/length/) you can use length or size().  You can chain jquery selectors with [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to count the inner spans.  For example,

```
<script>
  var n = $(".x").find("span").length;
  alert(n);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#id od 1st span").children("span").size();
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.x span').length
```

this should work

http://jsfiddle.net/6kWdf/

Answer (score -1):

You could use this for example:

```
$('#showTotalBarcodeCnt').html($("#barcodeLabelList").find("label").length);
```

Thanks